# How to round down

Tags: python

It is easy to round up, doing string formatting:

```
>>> x=0.115
>>> '%.2f' % x
'0.12'
```

How would I round down with string formatting? I.e., to get 0.11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floor your number:

```
import math
v = 0.115
math.floor(v*100)/100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = 0.115
>>> '%.2f' % (int(x * 100) / 100.0)
'0.11'
```

Comment: Note that as `int()` always truncates towards zero, this solution will round up for negative numbers.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Perhaps OP wants that